# How to suggest synonyms using ngram and collocation concept in python

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, n-gram

My aim to suggest synonym of a given word. Using ngram I can able to find out different kind of collocations. But I cannot expand my scope to figure out the synonyms.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd use a `PreparedStatement` as a matter of course.  Are the `str` and the "words" the same case?

Comment: Don't concatenate values into a query. Use prepared statements with parameters.

Comment: Unrelated but: do ***NOT*** use the system (or sys) account for regular work, never. Create a regular user and use _that_. This is like working as root in Linux all the time. Don't do it.

Comment: I now try with prepared statements but again same result.